# Guide for extending the Javascript language on VsCode for a 3rd party API

Tags: javascript, api, visual-studio-code

So I've started using VsCode over Atom recently and love it, the issue is I develop for software that uses its own JS API with no proper integration into anything. 
I've started trying to implement my own autocomplete/intellisense structure using their pdf into VsCode to speed up my workflow, currently I'm simply using a JS file that is full of empty functions and objects with a bunch of JSDoc comments to help VsCode Intellisense identify what's what, that seems to be working fine so far but it means importing this "useless" file into every project I work on. 
I looked into extending the JS language using a language server but that seems way too complex for what I need (plus it looks like I'd be building the entire Javascript language from scratch). 
Does anyone have any recommendations ect?

Kind regards.

Edit
Sorry I also would like the ability for it to pass linting as right now it gets a bit funky with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely do not need an extension for that your example use case.

VS Code's intellisense for libraries is powered by [`.d.ts` typing declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html). The declaration files for the library you are using can either be written in your current workspace as you are currently doing, or—preferably—shipped with the library itself. Many npm modules ship their with typing definitions files, while other libraries have typing definition files provided by the community through [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

You alternatively bundle `d.ts` types file into as a separate npm package that you include in any project that needs them

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate it. 
This looks far simpler and far more like what I need. 
Now to transfer over 200 pages of pdf documentation to an actual "psuedo" api.

Comment: Hey i'm not sure if you'll see this, I've run into a couple issues regarding .d.ts files. 
Specifically it looks like I still have to include them in my project structure per project, it looks like they're basically just a typescript version of the empty function and variable script I was writing in JS. Is this accurate or am I missing something?

Comment: One big advantage of `d.ts` files is that you can ship them with your library or even package just the `d.ts` files into their own npm package (this is what DefinitelyTyped does)

Comment: Right ok. Hmmm, the web dev I do is for After Effects, they use a chromium backend to host a website as a User Interface. The thing is they have an api that doesn't come as a library or even files I can use, they use .jsx extension (not javascript xml they just decided to use that extension ages ago) and because there's no offical support for IDEs there's no intellisense and linting has a fit. 
I also don't use npm in my projects.